# LineCollection animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

For the following code (MWE), if the line

```
ax.set_axis_off()
```

is commented out, then the animation shows nothing.  Otherwise, the animation works as expected.  My question is: why?

```
from itertools import tee

import numpy as np

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')           # noqa
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation, FFMpegWriter
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, BoundaryNorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


def make_segs(x, y):
    xs = np.array(list(pairwise(x)))  # (n,2)
    ys = np.array(list(pairwise(y)))  # (n,2)
    segs = np.stack((xs, ys), axis=-1)  # (n,2,2)
    return segs


class _AnimationHelper():
    def __init__(self, xs, ys, z, colors=['r', 'g']):
        self.segs = np.array([make_segs(x, y) for x, y in zip(xs, ys)])
        self.z = z
        self.colors = colors
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.lns = []
        self.ani = FuncAnimation(
            self.fig,
            self.update,
            interval=200,
            init_func=self.init,
            frames=self.segs.shape[1],
            blit=True)

    def init(self):
        m, n = self.segs.shape[:2]
        self.fig.set_size_inches(m*5, 5)
        self.axes = self.fig.subplots(
            nrows=1, ncols=m, sharey='row')
        self.fig.tight_layout()
        cmap = ListedColormap(self.colors)
        norm = BoundaryNorm([0, 0.5, 1], cmap.N)
        zero = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.int32)
        for i in range(m):
            inds = (zero + i) == self.z
            ln = LineCollection([], cmap=cmap, norm=norm, lw=2, animated=True)
            ln.set_array(inds)
            self.lns.append(ln)

            ax = self.axes[i]
            ax.add_collection(ln)
            ax.set_xlim(0, n)
            ax.set_axis_off()  # <---- HERE

        self.axes[0].set_ylim(0, 1.1)
        for i in range(1, m):
            self.axes[i].tick_params(left=False)
        return self.lns

    def update(self, ind):
        print(ind)
        m = self.segs.shape[0]
        for i in range(m):
            self.lns[i].set_segments(self.segs[i, :(ind + 1)])
        return self.lns


N = 20
M = 3

x = np.arange(N)
xs = np.repeat(x.reshape([1, -1]), M, axis=0)
ys = np.exp(-xs) + 0.05*np.random.random((M, N))
z = np.array([2]*4 + [1]*5 + [0]*5 + [2]*5)

helper = _AnimationHelper(xs, ys, z)
writer = FFMpegWriter(fps=5, codec='mpeg4')
helper.ani.save('out/test_saveani.mp4', writer=writer, dpi=80)
```

Comment: Can you remove the `animated=True` in `LineCollection` and try again?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For saving a figure, the use of `blit` is not necessary. If that is left out, the figure is saved correctly. However, the figure size change is not taken into account, because the animation is created before that change. Creating the figure and all the axes before creating the animation works perfectly fine though, even with blitting being used.

```
from itertools import tee

import numpy as np

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')           # noqa
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation, FFMpegWriter
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap, BoundaryNorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)


def make_segs(x, y):
    xs = np.array(list(pairwise(x)))  # (n,2)
    ys = np.array(list(pairwise(y)))  # (n,2)
    segs = np.stack((xs, ys), axis=-1)  # (n,2,2)
    return segs


class _AnimationHelper():
    def __init__(self, xs, ys, z, colors=['r', 'g']):
        self.segs = np.array([make_segs(x, y) for x, y in zip(xs, ys)])
        self.z = z
        self.colors = colors
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.lns = []

        m, n = self.segs.shape[:2]
        self.fig.set_size_inches(m*5, 5, forward=True)
        self.axes = self.fig.subplots(
            nrows=1, ncols=m, sharey='row')
        self.fig.tight_layout()

        self.ani = FuncAnimation(
            self.fig,
            self.update,
            interval=200,
            init_func=self.init,
            frames=self.segs.shape[1],
            blit=True)

    def init(self):
        m, n = self.segs.shape[:2]
        cmap = ListedColormap(self.colors)
        norm = BoundaryNorm([0, 0.5, 1], cmap.N)
        zero = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.int32)
        for i in range(m):
            inds = (zero + i) == self.z
            ln = LineCollection([], cmap=cmap, norm=norm, lw=2, animated=True)
            ln.set_array(inds)
            self.lns.append(ln)

            ax = self.axes[i]
            ax.add_collection(ln)
            ax.set_xlim(0, n)
            #ax.set_axis_off()  # <---- HERE

        self.axes[0].set_ylim(0, 1.1)
        for i in range(1, m):
            self.axes[i].tick_params(left=False)
        return self.lns

    def update(self, ind):
        print(ind)
        m = self.segs.shape[0]
        for i in range(m):
            self.lns[i].set_segments(self.segs[i, :(ind + 1)])
        return self.lns


N = 20
M = 3

x = np.arange(N)
xs = np.repeat(x.reshape([1, -1]), M, axis=0)
ys = np.exp(-xs) + 0.05*np.random.random((M, N))
z = np.array([2]*4 + [1]*5 + [0]*5 + [2]*5)

helper = _AnimationHelper(xs, ys, z)
writer = FFMpegWriter(fps=5, codec='mpeg4')
helper.ani.save('test_saveani.mp4', writer=writer, dpi=80)
```

The above now even allows to use an interactive backend, `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` and showing the figure via `plt.show()`.

Comment: Finally!  Thank you!  The figure and axes SHOULD be set up outside the `init` function.  That makes much more sense.

Comment: And if I set `blit=False`, the quality is really poor.  I have to manually adjust the animation writer to get the desired quality.  Not sure why.

Comment: Wow, I don't think that should happen. There is at least programmatically no reason for that. I also do not observe any such difference when running this myself.

Comment: Oops, sorry, for this MWE, the `blit` does not make a difference.  However, I have a more fancy animation where `blit` really makes a difference.  Thank you!