# Animate changing amount of lines between points - Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, animation

**This question is different from other animation questions as I'm trying to animate an alternating amounts of lines between points. For example, it may be between 3 points or 50 points.**

Using the data frame below, the points are labelled in `Item`. The first two time stamps contain 4 points but this drops to 3 points for the final two time stamps. I'm trying to find an efficient way to combine all the potential lines act each time stamp into a single call function to animate.

The issue I'm having is I'm plotting each line manually. Therefore, the line between each point is currently hard-coded, which doesn't account for a change in the amount of lines.

I need something that combines the available lines first and then passes this to the animation.

For instance, `A, B, C, D` are currently labelled points in the first two time points. But this drops to `A, B, C` for the last two time points.

This following doesn't account for alternating amounts of lines.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4],  
    'Item' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    'GroupA_X' : [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 6, 2, 1, 6, 7, 2, 7, 8], 
    'GroupA_Y' : [2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 5, 2, 2, 6, 5, 1, 5, 4], 
})

GA_X = np.array(df.groupby('Time')['GroupA_X'].apply(list).tolist())
GA_Y = np.array(df.groupby('Time')['GroupA_Y'].apply(list).tolist())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (6,6))
ax.grid(False)
ax.set_xlim(0,10)
ax.set_ylim(0,10)

data = np.stack([GA_X, GA_Y], axis = 2)

vector1 = ax.annotate('', xy = data[0][0], 
            xytext = data[0][1], 
            arrowprops={'arrowstyle': "-", 'color': 'black'}, 
            ha='center')

vector2 = ax.annotate('', xy = data[0][0], 
            xytext = data[0][2], 
            arrowprops={'arrowstyle': "-", 'color': 'black'}, 
            ha='center')

vector3 = ax.annotate('', xy = data[0][1], 
            xytext = data[0][2], 
            arrowprops={'arrowstyle': "-", 'color': 'black'}, 
            ha='center')

def animate(i):
    start1 = np.r_[data[i, 0]]
    end1 = np.r_[data[i, 1]]

    vector1.set_position(start1)
    vector1.xy = end1    

    start2 = np.r_[data[i, 0]]
    end2 = np.r_[data[i, 2]]

    vector2.set_position(start2)
    vector2.xy = end2 

    start3 = np.r_[data[i, 1]]
    end3 = np.r_[data[i, 2]]

    vector3.set_position(start3)
    vector3.xy = end3 

    return 

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval = 100, blit = False)
```

Out:

```
data = np.stack([GA_X, GA_Y], axis = 2)

axis = normalize_axis_index(axis, result_ndim)

AxisError: axis 2 is out of bounds for array of dimension 2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to animate a Polygon (defined by arrays) with Python & Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53061933/how-to-animate-a-polygon-defined-by-arrays-with-python-matplotlib)

Comment: @ Diziet Asahi. I have tried to adapt this but it's slightly different. I need to animate lines

Comment: There are hundreds of examples on how to [animate a line plot](http://www.google.de/search?q=matplotlib+animate+line+plot) around. If you have many lines (>50) you may consider using a line collection (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52723813/linecollection-animation)), but for small numbers or low framerates that would probably be overkill.

Comment: What if the number of lines is dynamic. For example, it could be 10 for one frame or 100 for another frame

Comment: Could you clarify a little what plot you're trying to make. You want to create one line for each "Item" at each timestep ? So i.e. tiimestep 2 would have 4 lines ( one for each item, but timestep 3 should have 3 lines ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understanding you want to plot at every time-step i a line for each item where the two points of each line are first the (x,y) in the time-step i and second the point (x,y) in the time step i+1.

(so if the item don't appear in the time-step i+1 we won't display the line for that item in step i)

Assuming this I suggest that:

1) use the dataframe itself instead of changing it to a np.array

2) move the creation of the lines inside the animate function

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from numpy import random 
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time' : [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4],  
    'Item' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],                  
    'GroupA_X' : [3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 6, 2, 1, 6, 7, 2, 7, 8], 
    'GroupA_Y' : [2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 5, 5, 2, 2, 6, 5, 1, 5, 4],                         
        })

# generating the figure configs
frame_num = len(df1['Time'].unique()) 
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 10), ylim=(0, 10))
line, = ax1.plot([], [], lw=2)
plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')

plotlays, itemColors = [2], {'A':"black",
                             'B':"red",
                             'C':"blue",
                             'D':"purple"}


def animate(i):

    lines = []
    # filtering items per time step
    for (row_idx, row) in df1[df1["Time"] == i+1].iterrows():
        nextTimestep_item = df1[(df1["Time"] == i+2) & (df1["Item"] ==row["Item"])] 
        if nextTimestep_item.empty:
            # no plot if item is not on next timestep
            continue
        else:
            x = [row['GroupA_X'],nextTimestep_item['GroupA_X']]
            y = [row['GroupA_Y'],nextTimestep_item['GroupA_Y']]
            color = itemColors[row["Item"]]
            lobj = ax1.plot([],[],lw=2,color=color)[0]
            lobj.set_data(x, y)  
            lines.append(lobj)

    return lines

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 
                               frames=frame_num, interval=500, blit=True)

plt.show()
```